# Reading values from Comment Section in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

I am having **Comment** as Input, I need to retrieve values from that. how can i achieve this?

Input **Comment**= "service-maintenance,I have been contacted about an airbag recall. When can I book?Make : Nissan\nModel : X-TRAIL\nSeries : T324\nDescription : X-TRAIL Desc\nBodyType : 4X4\n";

I need to retrieve **Make ,Model, Series ,Description ,BodyType** from this input.

**Note: if values not present, that should be Empty.**

```
// Reading Make value from Comment Section
String makevalue = comments.contains("Make :") ? comments.substring(comments.lastIndexOf("Make :"), comments.indexOf("Model :")) : "";
make = makevalue.length() > 0 ? makevalue.substring(makevalue.lastIndexOf(":") + 1) : "";
System.out.println(" Make is ::::::: " + make);
// Reading Model value from Comment Section
String modelvalue = comments.contains("Model :") ? comments.substring(comments.lastIndexOf("Model :"), comments.indexOf("Series :")) : "";
model = modelvalue.length() > 0 ? Modelvalue.substring(modelvalue.lastIndexOf(":") + 1) : "";
System.out.println(" Model is ::::::: " + model);
// Reading Description value from Comment Section
String descvalue = comments.contains("Description :") ? comments.substring(comments.lastIndexOf("Description :"), comments.indexOf("BodyType :")) : "";
description = descvalue.length() > 0 ? descvalue.substring(descvalue.lastIndexOf(":") + 1) : "";
System.out.println(" Description is ::::::: " + description);
```

This sample code works when All values are present in the same order (Make,Model,Series,Description,BodyType)

Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Note that you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names should be written in camelCase.

Comment: Hi @MC Emperor,
I have changed variable as per your suggestions by using Java Naming Conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this by using regex:

```
    String comment= "service-maintenance,I have been contacted about an airbag recall. When can I book?Make : Nissan\nModel : X-TRAIL\nSeries : T324\nDescription : X-TRAIL Desc\nBodyType : 4X4\n";
    String pattern = "Make : (.*)\nModel : (.*)\nSeries : (.*)\nDescription : (.*)\nBodyType : (.*)\n";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(comment);

    if (m.find( )) {
        //System.out.println(m.group(0));
        System.out.println("Make: "+m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Model: "+m.group(2));
        System.out.println("Series: "+m.group(3));
        System.out.println("Description: "+m.group(4));
        System.out.println("BodyType: "+m.group(5));
     }else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
     }
```

Output:

```
Make: Nissan
Model: X-TRAIL
Series: T324
Description: X-TRAIL Desc
BodyType: 4X4
```

If you uncomment the first syso you will get this output:

```
Make : Nissan
Model : X-TRAIL
Series : T324
Description : X-TRAIL Desc
BodyType : 4X4
```

EDIT:
Additional solution to parse optional paramters

```
    String comment= "service-maintenance,I have been contacted about an airbag recall. When can I book?Make : Nissan\nModel : X-TRAIL\nSeries : T324\nDescription : X-TRAIL Desc\nBodyType : 4X4\n";
    String pattern = "(Make|Model|Series|Description|BodyType) : (.*)\n";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(comment);

    while (m.find()) {
        //System.out.println(m.group(0));
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + "=" + m.group(2));
     }
```

Now the output is:

```
Make=Nissan
Model=X-TRAIL
Series=T324
Description=X-TRAIL Desc
BodyType=4X4
```

And the same output will be if if uncomment syso line. And of course you can remove some parameters and everything should work as expected. If all parameters are removed then output will be empty.

Comment: Hi @Uata,
Thanks for your reply.
Whatever values present in Comment,that need to be retrieved, for eg. If i remove Model from Input, remaining values like Make,Description exx retrieved except that Model, in this case Model is empty. (service-maintenance,I have been contacted about an airbag recall. When can I book?Make : Nissan\nSeries : T324\nDescription : X-TRAIL Desc\nBodyType : 4X4\n";) Can u check above input

Comment: @Justin check my edit. I've made a small update in pattern to fulfill your requirements;)

Comment: Hi @Uata,
I have tried the additional Solution which you provided. it prints nothing. while debugging, inside while loop it didn't come. Can you please help me??

Comment: @Justin ahh yes. Sorry. All backslashes in the comment String have been doubled during copying. Now everything should be fine but please double check if you don't have multiple backslashes in the comment message

Comment: Hi @Uata,
Thanks for your EDIT Answer which satisfies my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can first split based on `?` which will give me input parameters.
2. Then split based on `\n` this will give me array of parameters
3. Split based on `:` to get ket and value pair.
   **Note**
   This is very specific solution for given comment, anything changes in this will might broke the code .

   ```
   String comment = "service-maintenance,I have been contacted about an airbag recall. When can I book?Make : Nissan\nModel : X-TRAIL\nSeries : T324\nDescription : X-TRAIL Desc\nBodyType : 4X4\n";

   String[] arr = comment.split("\\?");
   String[] newArr =  arr[1].split("\n");

   for (String string : newArr) {
       String[] arrValue = string.split(":");
       System.out.println("key: "+ arrValue[0] +" value: "+ arrValue[1]);

   }
   ```

Comment: Hi @Sumit,
Thanks for your reply.
I need to assign retrieved values to variable. for eg. if Input contains Only Model means, that Model value is assigned to Model Variable. remaining variable's values are empty . please let me know the solution...

Comment: @Justin inside for loop you can put if-else case to check key name agains your model like if(arrValue[0].equals("Meke")) then assign to that field and so one

Comment: Hi @Sumit,
Got your point. But I received dynamic content as input for eg,Input be like (Make : Nissan\nModel : X-TRAIL\nSeries : T324\nDescription : X-TRAIL Desc\nBodyType : 4X4\n") In this case i can't able to split by "?". right?? Could you please help me?

Comment: @Justin if there is no clear contract then no solution will work, unless you want to create some kind of Machine learning model, In traditional programming you must have clear contract about how your input will be, other wise no logic will work.

Comment: @Justin  you can use #Uata solution to have little more flexibility in terms of input pre and post extra data, but this will only work if input don't change the order of parameter

Comment: Hi @Sumit,
I agreed. that was my mistake.understood. can you help me?

Comment: @Justin what else you need here?

Answer (score 0):

To get the value after separating the text string and having it in a list as mentioned above, if the titles are always constant you can substring the length of each title to get the value without spaces like:

`public static final int MAKE_LENGHT = ("Make : ").length();
 String make = string[0].substring(makeTitle);`

Result: make = "Nissan"